# Inquiry about Sentry's Capabilities for Detecting N+1 Query Problems in React GraphQL Node.js Project

Tags: reactjs, node.js, graphql, sentry

I'm reaching out to inquire about Sentry's capabilities in detecting specific performance issues.

My technology stack includes React for the front end, GraphQL for the API layer, Node.js for server-side logic, and PostgreSQL as the database management system.

Here are the specific areas we are looking for assistance with:

```
Frontend Issues in Real Time
Backend Issues in Real Time
DB Query Performance Analytics
Frontend & Backend Performance Issues (Like N+1 Issues)
```

does Sentry have the capability to detect and alert about N+1 query problems, especially related to GraphQL queries, in real-time?

We are eager to know how Sentry can assist us in identifying and resolving these issues effectively. Your insights and recommendations will be highly valuable to us.